# tool tip getting hidden in the container

Tags: javascript, css, html, d3.js, rickshaw

i am working in the d3 library and also in rickshaw. in my graph i have a tool tip which displays when hovered the graph bars. the thing is that, its getting hidden in the container when the last bar is in hovered. its getting hidden in the container. only partial tool tip is getting visible. is there any way to fix it or is there any changes to be made in CSS. here is my code:

the graph which i am trying to do is like this http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html . but i am putting this inside a container, so that the last tool tip is getting hidden inside the container.

Comment: Increase the size of the container?